# How do I remove duplicates in an SQL query without using Distinct?

Tags: sql, select, distinct

There are duplicates in the results of the query below. My question is how to get rid of `subTaskName` duplicates without using `distinct`?

```
SELECT  tasks.priority, (SELECT tasks.name FROM tasks WHERE tasks.taskid ='11377') AS taskName,
        tasks.name AS subTaskName,u.name,tasks.deadline,tasks.created,a.duration AS durata,tasks.parentID,tasks.userid ,tasks.finished,
        tasks.estimated,tasks.taskid,tasks.section,tasks.tags
        FROM tasks 
        INNER JOIN users u 
        ON tasks.assignerid = u.userid
        INNER JOIN activities a 
        ON tasks.parentID = a.taskid
        WHERE tasks.parentID='11377' 
        ORDER BY tasks.taskid
        DESC
```

[Use this link to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLmvW.png)

Comment: I can imagine some horrible manipulations with `COUNT` - but I doubt that will be "improving" of query. Why do that? Also, please, _add code correctly_ - I'm sure no one want to use microscope to figure out what's in your query

Comment: Would you copy-and-paste the text of your query and result to improve visibility?

Comment: you can use Ctrl +scroll to see the image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After where clause include: GROUP BY `tasks.name`