# How to search for matching staff number in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to sql and trying to come up with a sql query which will list me the duplicate staff which were created in our system. 
We have one staff which is created with id as 1234 and the same user has another account starting with staff id 01234. Is there anyway i can get the matching staff
Once i come up with correct duplicates i will than want to delete the accounts which don't have "0" at the start e.g deleted 1234 and only keep 01234

below is the sql

```
SELECT     tps_user.tps_title AS [Name] , tps_user_type.tps_title AS [User Type]
FROM       tps_user INNER JOIN
                      tps_user_type ON tps_user.tps_user_type_guid = tps_user_type.tps_guid
WHERE     (tps_user.tps_title IN
                          (SELECT     tps_title AS users
                            FROM          tps_user AS t1
                            WHERE      (tps_deleted = 0)
                            GROUP BY tps_title
                            HAVING      (COUNT(tps_title) > 1))) AND (tps_user.tps_deleted = 0)
```

Comment: if you `convert` '01234' to an `int` the leading `0` is removed and the value is represented as `1234`

Comment: @sanees : can you give more details of the table structure . So that we can help to write the query . as in the able comment  making them its is one way to solve the issue .

Comment: the query which i have at the moment is listing me on display name, which i think is not quiet right because there can be two people with same name

Comment: in the above query, tps_name is the field which contains the staff id which i don't know how to fit in the above query. tps title is the display name of the user

Answer (score 1):

When you do you select try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(INT,ID)
FROM your_table
WHERE ...
```

OR

```
SELECT ID
FROM your_table
WHERE ...
GROUP BY ID
```

This will convert all the id's to an int temporarily so when the distinct evaluates duplicates everything will be uniform to give you an accurate representation of the duplicates.

IF you don't want to convert them maybe convert them and insert them into a temporary table and add a flag to which ones have a leading zero. Or convert them then append a zero after you delete the duplicates since you want that anyway. It is easy to append a 0.

Comment: The reason i am not using distinct is , i would like to see the duplicates which i can than later delete from the system

Comment: IF you search this question if will answer it for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21160200/how-do-i-remove-duplicates-in-an-sql-query-without-using-distinct

Comment: I will say though you may still need to convert them to an INT. I updated my answer to include a group by if you need help using one.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select t1.stringId
from mytable t1
inner join mytable t2 on Convert(INT, t1.intId) = CONVERT(INT, t2.intId)
where t1.stringId not like '0%'
```

This should list all the persons that have duplicates but do not start with 0.

Comment: problem with the above is we have two types of user ones which have user id's as alphabets and then some of other staff which have numbers as staff id's, the problems only lies with the number staff id's . is there any way we can amend the top query which excludes 1st zero and shows me the results

Comment: where tps_user.tps_name not like '0%' and tps_user.tps_name not    like 'a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,x,y,z'  i came up with this but its not working

Comment: i would like to specify do not show me any results if the tps_name has any alphabets in it a-z

Comment: The CONVERT funciton will also fail if you have alphanumeric characters in your db.

Answer (score 0):

the below query will give you the list of duplicates with same Name and title. -

```
SELECT     tps_user.tps_title AS [Name] , 
           tps_user_type.tps_title AS [UserType], 
           COUNT(*) Duplicate_Count
FROM       tps_user 
INNER JOIN tps_user_type 
           ON tps_user.tps_user_type_guid = tps_user_type.tps_guid 
group by   tps_user.tps_title, tps_user_type.tps_title
having COUNT(*) > 1 
order by Duplicate_Count desc
```

Comment: SELECT    Distinct tps_user.tps_title AS [Name] ,   tps_user_type.tps_title AS [User Type]
FROM         tps_user INNER JOIN
                      tps_user_type ON tps_user.tps_user_type_guid = tps_user_type.tps_guid
       where tps_user.tps_name not like '0%' and tps_user.tps_name not like '%[a-z]%'
       and (tps_user.tps_deleted = 0)